# Filtering data frame by multiple columns from another data frame

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two data frames, and I am trying to filter out one of the data frames using the two columns from the other one. In my example, I am trying to filter out the data by both the `year` and `ID` column in `df` using the `df2` data frame. For example:

I would like to filter out all the dates that have `ID` 1 in 2010, `ID` 3 in 2012, `ID` 2 in 2010, and `ID` 4 in 2013 from the data frame `df`. So that the output only has the dates from 2010 for `ID` 1, only 2012 for `ID` 3, 2010 for `ID` 2, and 2013 for `ID` 4 together in a new data frame.

```
library(lubridate)
date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("26-12-2010"), dmy("20-12-2013"), by = "days"), 500)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df2 <- data.frame(year = c(2010, 2012, 2010,2013),
                  ID = c(1,3,2,4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but you can paste together the combinations of years and ID in both data.frames and then use one to filter the other. Probably not the best way if you have a large data.frame though.

```
df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(paste0(lubridate::year(date), "_", ID) %in% paste0(df2$year,"_", df2$ID))
```

```
         date        x        y ID
1  2010-12-26 74119.46 839347.8  1
2  2010-12-27 72401.02 891788.1  2
3  2010-12-31 66940.94 810089.6  1
4  2012-01-02 68214.97 881200.1  3
5  2012-01-07 70595.92 863277.7  3
6  2012-01-12 79799.85 857738.5  3
7  2012-01-17 61102.50 848880.6  3
8  2012-01-22 71798.29 883455.7  3
9  2012-01-27 61550.93 889447.7  3
10 2012-02-01 69863.50 838101.4  3
11 2012-02-06 71202.38 873705.6  3
12 2012-02-11 60124.56 828661.6  3
13 2012-02-16 65963.74 824347.5  3
14 2012-02-21 79347.69 818929.1  3
15 2012-02-26 68082.87 879863.1  3
16 2012-03-02 68661.00 891477.0  3
17 2012-03-07 71369.69 849595.6  3
18 2012-03-12 73265.85 834035.4  3
19 2012-03-17 70777.06 833344.5  3
20 2012-03-22 72104.04 881329.5  3
21 2012-03-27 75471.59 848650.2  3
22 2012-04-01 77590.13 867834.6  3
23 2012-04-06 75664.27 828857.6  3
24 2012-04-11 65789.62 814059.0  3
25 2012-04-16 72841.91 893683.3  3
26 2012-04-21 61047.06 805820.7  3
27 2012-04-26 77232.51 896022.5  3
28 2012-05-01 77553.05 817557.6  3
29 2012-05-06 75597.76 899616.4  3
```

Perhaps a more efficient way would be to use a join:

```
df$year = lubridate::year(df$date)
dplyr::left_join(df2, df, by=c("ID", "year")) %>% na.omit()
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using base R is to use `merge`.

```
library(lubridate)
df$year = lubridate::year(df$date)

merge(df, df2)
```

Since, `df2` only has the two columns, then the merge is limited to using those columns. If we were to write out the columns that we want to merge by, then it would look something like this.

```
merge(df,df2[c("year","ID")],by=c("year","ID"))
```